# rails formtastic more complex associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

so I have the following models:

Country
City
Company
CompanyOffice

The connections are like this:

Company -1:n-> CompanyOffice -> City -> Country

So now I have a formtastic form for the Company model. What works fine is changing everything in the Company model.
But I want to let the user type in multiple addresses for the company.

I tried:

```
= semantic_form_for current_user.company, :url => url do |f|
  = f.input :name, :label => 'Company name'
  = f.input :logo, :label => 'Company Logo'
  ...

  = f.inputs :for => :company_offices do |co, i|
    = co.select :city, :collection => City.all, :label => 'City'
    = co.input :street, :label => 'Street'
```

This doesn't work. How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have nested attributes in your models? [see](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)

Comment: yes I have and actually this makes it not work. So adding the nested attrs makes formtastic display no fields in this area. removing them displays the fields, but I can not save because it is expecting an CompanyOffice object not an array of the objects

Comment: well, if you wanna dynamically add company offices in one form by clicking add/remove then you need this [approach](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) and besides that i do not see any semantic_fields_for

Comment: when I use semantic_fields_for I get the following error: undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class and the error is pointing to the line of the "semantic_fields_for"

Comment: and where did you get .select method on input? co.select does not seems to me formtastically correct? how about co.input :city, :as => :select ?

Comment: Also correct yes. So I found the problem thanks to your railscasts link and the :as => select. I had to create an empty CompanyOffice in order to be shown in the form.